# Should I stop editing?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

A lot of edits I do are when I'm in the review queues. If I see something that obviously doesn't add anything to the validity of the question I remove it. Most of the times that ends up being Hi, thanks, help I'm a beginner, etc. I was following what I read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021).

The problem is a large amount of these are getting rejected, to the point where I've been temporarily banned from queues and editing. If I'm going to get banned for doing what I thought was improving the site, should I just stop making these edits?

Comment: What are they being rejected for? [Your most recent](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14440810) was simply a conflict, not necessarily a bad edit. [One before that](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13708729) was a pointless edit given the rest of the question, but got 2 approvals anyway. Have you been through [the list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2157447/jeremy-w?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and read the reasons?

Comment: Is the answer to this question not obvious?  Are you expecting people to tell you, "no, you should keep doing the thing that is getting you banned."?  Clearly what you're doing now is not appropriate.  Whether you want to just not suggest edits or learn how to suggest *appropriate* edits that *won't* be rejected is of course up to you.

Comment: Most of the rejected edits seem to be removing noise like _"thanks"_. Maybe the edits were considered to be "too minor". You also got unlucky, as a couple were rejected because of conflicting subsequent edits.

Comment: @Cerbrus Edits rejected due to conflicts don't contribute towards the edit ban.

Comment: Jeremy, I'd suggest: don't stop editing, but try to improve _everything_ there is to improve about a question / answer. If a post has more flaws than just the "thanks" noise, edit that as well.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's a good point and I'll do that moving forward. Should I stop editing just the small thanks, hi, beginner type posts then, if that's all I would be changing?

Comment: @Servy I appreciate the condescension but obviously the answer wasn't obvious to me as I needed to ask the community of their thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Also, do not edit crap. Even if your edit cleans up all cleanable issues with a question, that doesn't matter if the end result is a really well written but horribly off topic question, or a "do my homework" request. If the question should be closed or downvoted, I'd refrain from editing it. Not only does it waste your time but that of three reviewers as well.

Comment: @JeremyW It wasn't obvious to you that you being banned for suggesting edits inappropriately was an indication that your edits weren't appropriate?  If you honestly think that people are banned for no reason, and that we want them to continue making edits that we banned them for making, then yes, you should stop editing.  If you being banned is not an *obvious* indication that *something* is wrong then you shouldn't be editing posts.

Comment: @l4mpi That's a good point. I'd never thought about it like that. I'll do that moving forward as well, thanks!

Comment: @Servy No it wasn't obvious to me because I was following instructions from the meta stack exchange link I provided that assured me I was doing the right thing.

Comment: [**If you are going to edit a post, make sure you're substantively improving it**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/) (emphasis original)

Comment: In defense of this question, we should keep in mind that robo reviewers are a thing and just seeing an edit *remove* stuff (regardless of what it actually is) triggers many of the reviewers to reject the edit…

Comment: @poke As there are no known-good suggested edit review audits, robo-reviewers in the suggested edits queue simply reject every edit they see without reading the edit at all. On the other side you have well-meaning but inexperienced users who regularly approve crap edits. Then you have the users who actually review (for better or worse) the edits and make (mostly) informed decisions. These users sometimes make mistakes, but for the most part (and in this case) they are correct. However, when combined with the other two groups, anything can happen.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As one of the lowest-reputation (as I write this) users to earn Archaeologist, Research Assistant, and just now Copy Editor, I feel I have to write this.

You ***cannot*** give up after *one ban*. Get up, *look at why you were banned*, and try to fix the problem. Looking over your history, it seems crystal clear that your edits aren't *thorough* enough.

I've found that removing fluff from posts isn't really a good edit on its own—leave that to 2K users. Instead, add in the removal of fluff with *other* edits, such as:

- Fix terrible spelling and/or grammar
- See that gigantic stack trace and/or code dump in the question? Put it into a code block.
- If you find a link to an image URL with the text "enter image description here", you can turn the link into an actual image.
- Code spans by themselves on their own line, especially multi-line code spans, usually look much better as a code block.
- Recognize what is code and put it in backticks:

  - Words and phrases in camelCase or snake_case
  - Words followed by a set of parentheses
- CSS looks much better if you add `<!-- language: lang-css -->`, *especially* if it contains color hexes or ID selectors because those contain `#` characters which are rendered as comments by default.

This list could possibly also be linked to for users posting comments as answers—if you keep these in mind while patrolling the questions page, it's easy to gain 50 reputation in a *day*, as I have done on several occasions.

Comment: I appreciate this answer. Going forward I'll definitely leave the removing of fluff to the users with 2k+ rep and be more thorough with my edits going forward.

Comment: been meaning to ask somewhere, how does one turn a link to an image into an embedded image in the post?

Comment: @DForck42 you add an exclamation point before the brackets around the link text.

Comment: To quote (movie reference) Billy Madison's statement:  "If your dog goes missing [a bad post is made], after one day's search [a single ban] do you just give up? No!  You get out there and you find that f@$%^*$ dog!" ;-)

Comment: Another useful, but relatively minor, edit is fixing tags, if necessary.  Especially if the question doesn't have a language tag.

Comment: A bit of a nitpick, but *"variable names, class names, or function names"* could be more simply: *"indentifiers"*